# Resonance frequency of a circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, resonance

I have a question concerning the resonance (or anti-resonance) frequency of a circuit. Will taking into account frequency-dependent behavior of the passive components change (skin and proximity effect in resistors, and flux penetration in inductors) change the resonance frequency of the circuit?

Comment: What does the circuit's transfer function tell you?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand the question.

Comment: @Andy it is defined as the ratio of the output and input signals in the frequency domain, if it is what you are asking...

Comment: In the absence of any circuit I presumed you could at least state the transfer function. Yes, that is what it is.

Comment: Suppose you have a voltage supplying a very complex circuit with different capacitors, inductors and resistors. Does the impedance of the circuit change if you take into account the frequency-dependent behavior of each parameter compared to when all values are constant? Specifically the resonance/anti-resonance frequency?

Comment: It might or it might not. It all depends on the circuit or transfer function.

Comment: @Aka ok understood, thank you!